# Why does the MacBook M1 Max render edges so rough in scaled resolutions (1440p) on external 4K monitor?

Tags: macos, resolution, macbook-pro, macos-ventura

I recently moved to a MacBook Pro M1 Max and noticed edges don't look as smooth as they do in my Intel MacBook on my external 4K display. This only happens when using other scaled resolutions than 2160p (native) or 1080p (2x). I already tried BetterDisplay but it makes no difference.

I tried taking a screenshot, but they look exactly the same when compared side to side on the same laptop, so I took a photo:

Intel chip:

[image: Intel chip]

M1 Chip:

[image: M1 Chip]

Please notice that a weird black edge is rendered in the M1.

Comment: This also happens on a 1080p monitor plugged into my Macbook Air M1. The edges look over-sharpened or even look like bandwidth-related artifacts at times.

Answer (score 0):

This is the effect of a sharpen filter -also named "unsharp masking". A resized image can look a bit soft, so it's common to apply a sharpen filter afterwards to restore the original, well, sharpness.

If applied with too strong parameters, a sharpen filter typically results in the kind of artefact you are observing: fake black edges around bright objects, or fake white egdes around dark objects.

This is nicely illustrated on this picture taken from the wikipedia page on the [sharpen filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unsharp_masking) (top without filter, bottom with filter):
[image]

A sharpen filter with reasonnable parameters should not result in such edges. It seems that Apple has gone too far with the video output of the M1 model (but maybe this can be modified in the graphics settings).